# sorting issue in the date/time column in xamdatagrid

Tags: xamdatagrid

In WPF , while clicking on the header of the date-time column in xamdatagrid , they are sorting according to the month wise in format of (mm/dd/yyyy) .

I wanted it to be sorted according to the month and the format should be  (yyyy/mm/dd)

Waiting for yur reply

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are defined in XAML and you want to do this on a per-field basis, the following works:

```
xmlns:igDP="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
   .
   .
   .
<igDP:Field Name="DateOfBirth">
  <igDP:Field.Settings>
    <igDP:FieldSettings EditAsType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
      <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor}">
          <Setter Property="Mask" Value="yyyy/mm/dd" />
          <Setter Property="Format" Value="yyyy/MM/dd" />
        </Style>
      </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
    </igDP:FieldSettings>
  </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:Field>
```

You can abstract that style into a keyed-resource if you need to reuse it across several fields. If you want to have the formatting applied to all your DateTime fields without specifying individual Field.Settings, you can put the style directly your XamDataGrid.Resources.